# Google App Engine Deploy has stopped working in 2023 - Cannot read property '@google-cloud/pubsub' of undefined

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an App Engine project running on Node 14. It's a Next.JS app that is built and then deployed via cloud build.

When I was committing code back in December 2022, it worked perfectly fine. However, this month (February 2023), it's suddenly not working. I haven't touched the project in months, haven't changed anything. I've also force-locked all my package.json deps (removing the caret/tilde symbols in version numbers), but I get the following error:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Services to deploy:

descriptor:                  [/workspace/app.yaml]
source:                      [/workspace]
target project:              [foo]
target service:              [default]
target version:              [foo]
target url:                  [https://foo.nw.r.appspot.com]
target service account:      [App Engine default service account]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 73 files to Google Cloud Storage               ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build (HASH HERE) status: FAILURE
npm ERR! Cannot read property '@google-cloud/pubsub' of undefined
```

My pubsub definition is like this:

```
import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub';
```

My inkling would be that pubsub no longer allows these kinds of imports. But how is that even possible when I've locked the dependencies, and not touched anything in months?

And if not, any other ideas as to what could be causing it?

I have, of course, done the npm "turn it off and on again" with package lock and node_modules!

Also please note this only happens in the app engine deploy - the step in cloudbuild that compiles the code is fine.

Extra data from inside the cloudbuild's npm build part:

```
DEBUG: ***** CACHE MISS: "npm_modules"
Installing application dependencies.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running "node -v"
v14.21.2
Done "node -v" (6.244263ms)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running "npm --version"
6.14.17
Done "npm --version" (210.983956ms)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running "npm ci --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)"
npm ERR! Cannot read property '@google-cloud/pubsub' of undefined
```

#### cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]

timeout: "1600s"
```

#### app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: default
instance_class: F2
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Gcloud version will be whatever `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud` uses, I assume latest. My local is:

```
Google Cloud SDK 412.0.0
alpha 2022.12.09
beta 2022.12.09
bq 2.0.83
core 2022.12.09
gsutil 5.17
Updates are available...
```

#### The important thing to note is that this used to work a few months ago, and now it does not - *with no configuration changes*

Update:

This github issue also suggests that it could be an issue with the caching layer on google cloudbuild, which would explain the mystery lack of the first module it encounters (same issue on multiple projects) - it can't find the node_modules/ -- if it ends up being that then I'll close this question. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/233#issuecomment-1452453245

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "DEBUG=foo:* next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "DEBUG=foo:* next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test:cypress": "cypress run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "3.3.0",
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "4.1.2",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "6.4.2",
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "3.3.16",
    "critters": "0.0.7",
    "debug": "4.3.4",
    "firebase-admin": "11.0.1",
    "handlebars": "4.7.7",
    "handlebars-loader": "1.7.2",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.37",
    "next": "12.2.2",
    "nodemailer": "6.7.8",
    "puppeteer": "17.1.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "soap": "0.45.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.5",
    "use-persisted-state": "0.3.3",
    "uuid": "9.0.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.18.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "cypress": "10.7.0",
    "eslint": "8.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-jsconfig": "1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it with `import * as pubsub from '@google-cloud/pubsub';` - no dice

Comment: I've compared all the cloudbuild output logs and versions of everything and I'm 99% sure this must be a change somewhere internally with google cloud or the build images or something.

Comment: Another additional note: it works fine when building and deploying from my local CLI, using the exact same versions of node and npm 

Comment: Can you add the `gcloud -v` output? Also your `.yaml` file(s) may be relevant.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu Added some extra detail as requested but doubt it gives much extra info!

Comment: Have you tried switching to other node versions?

Comment: @PoalaAstrid Yep

Comment: Tried deleting the artifacts bucket too, no success either

Comment: Tried building a different app engine, in the same project, also used to work but now doesn't, and I'm getting `Cannot read property '@google-cloud/secret-manager' of undefined` - so it's not just pubsub...

Comment: Tried using `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk` instead, didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty confident that the issue is somehow related to the `next build` that is happening in your `npm build` script. It is unusual for you to run that locally (or in a separate Cloud Build build) before you run `gcloud app deploy`. The correct way to do this would be to add a `gcp-build` script to your `package.json` that runs `next build`.

```
"scripts": {
  "gcp-build": "next build",
}
```

This script will [get picked up by the GCP buildpacks when you deploy to GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step) and add some addition steps to the build:

1. all your `devDependencies` will be installed
2. `npm run gcp-build` will be executed
3. the `devDependencies` will be pruned from the final app image

None of the above explains why something suddenly regressed, but the other bit that is suspicious is that you have `@babel` stuff in your `devDependencies` and you are using ESM style imports. This is suspicious because Nodejs has been adding native support for ESM style imports but it was [an experimental feature that needed to be explicitly enabled](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system) by setting `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`. So you might try adding that line and seeing if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Ah yes, y'know I completely forgot about the existence of gcp-build - I've used that before but it clearly escaped my mind this time around. That does indeed fix it for node 14. Regarding @babel, I believe that's in there just to make eslint work properly, it's not for the actual build itself. The two projects I have been having this issue with use next and parcel respectively, and I believe both of those don't require the babel dependency, but eslint does in order to work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can finally rest now that this is fixed haha. Stressful!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with node v14. I replicated the problem with v14, but didn't face the problem with v12 and v16.

could you experiment with that?

Comment: Thanks Luciano for taking the time to replicate. You're correct that it's an issue with node 14, but my issue is still why, when no code was changed between the successful and failing builds, and no deprecation (or at least not until next year) has been announced

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `@google-cloud/pubsub` declared in the `dependencies` section of your `package.json`? If you do you also need to make sure you have updated your `package-lock.json` before you deploy to GAE. The lock file is always used as the source of truth if it is present, so a quick test would be to just delete it and check if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes I do. I've been using node for 12 or so years so I'd have to quit development forever if it were something as simple as not putting it in my package.json 

Comment: It's the same issue across two different projects (and two different @google/ packages) that both have similar cloud build setups and are both using node 14. It seems that support for node 14 has broken on cloudbuild, yet it should not have been deprecated AFAIK. It works fine locally with gcloud app deploy

Comment: Also it's likely that the reason it's happening on the @google/ packages are just that they're first alphabetically, not anything to do with the packages themselves

Comment: Could you post the contents of your package.json in the issue?

Comment: Okay, added for good measure @Matthew